# CSS problem in creating a flexible list in two columns

Tags: html, css

I want to use flex property to have a list in two columns and become one column when the content of each item is out of the display.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      .flexcontainer {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
      .leftflex,
      .rightflex {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        flex: 50%;
      }
      body {font-size: 30px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="flexcontainer">
      <span class="leftflex">
        <li>1 Lorem, ipsum.</li>
        <li>2 Lorem, ipsum.</li>
      </span>
      <span class="rightflex">
        <li>3 Lorem, ipsum.</li>
        <li>4 Lorem, ipsum.</li>
      </span>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]
but there are two problems here:

1. When I make the screen size smaller, each item becomes two lines but I want to have a single column before this happens.
   I want this:
   [image]
   but I've got this:
   [image]
   If I set `white-space: nowrap;` for the list, the text won't wrap even in single column and it a is problem for long items:
   [image]
   I know I can use `@media (max-width: #px)` but I want to change flex and wrap properties based on content not screen size only.
2. Apparently flex does not consider bullet of list in fitting contents and I don't know how to fix this
   (I tried to use `calc` function to set
   `flex: calc(50%-10px)` but didn't work.) :
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The problem is with `flex-basis`. If you remove `flex: 50%` (which basically means `flex-grow: 1` and `flex-basis: 50%`), you will essentially set `flex-basis` back to `auto`, and get the 1 column before the text begins wrapping. (might want to keep `flex-grow` so the whole container stills takes up a whole row).
2. As for the bullets, you can specify `list-style-position: inside`, that will get rid of that weird overlap thing.

**Your code will look like this:**

```css
.flexcontainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
.leftflex,
.rightflex {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer however it wasn't exactly what I wanted but I suppose it is the best solution. I wanted the list space to remain at 50%.
and also thanks for solving the second problem but still don't know why `calc` function doesn't work for `flex` and `flex-basis` property

Answer (score 1):

You can use with a grid

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      .flexcontainer {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(240px, 1fr) ) ;
      }
      .leftflex,
      .rightflex {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        flex: 50%;
      }
      body {font-size: 30px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="flexcontainer">
      <span class="leftflex">
        <li>1 Lorem, ipsum.</li>
        <li>2 Lorem, ipsum.</li>
      </span>
      <span class="rightflex">
        <li>3 Lorem, ipsum.</li>
        <li>4 Lorem, ipsum.</li>
      </span>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex-basis` to define a width where you want it to start wrapping. To prevent the bullets overlapping when there is more text in the list you can add some padding to compensate.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      .flexcontainer {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin: 0 -1rem;
      }
      .leftflex,
      .rightflex {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        flex: 50%;
        flex-basis: 250px;
        padding: 0 1rem;
      }
      body {font-size: 30px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="flexcontainer">
      <span class="leftflex">
        <li>1 Lorem, ipsum. flex-basis flex-basis flex-basis</li>
        <li>2 Lorem, ipsum. flex-basis flex-basis</li>
      </span>
      <span class="rightflex">
        <li>3 Lorem, ipsum. flex-basis flex-basis</li>
        <li>4 Lorem, ipsum.</li>
      </span>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```